# When is a compact Lie group endowed with a left-invariant complex structure a Kähler manifold of balanced manifold?

Tags: lie-groups, kahler-manifolds, hermitian-manifolds

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group having a left-invariant complex structure $J$.

Is there a hermitian metric $h$ in $G$, compatible with the complex structure $J$, such that $G$ is a Kähler manifold?

In the case it is not possible to turn $G$ into a Kähler manifold, does it hold that exist a hermitian metric such that $G$ is a balanced manifold? That is, $\Delta_d = 2 \Delta_\overline{\partial}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the first question:  Only when $G$ is abelian.  In fact, if $G$ is not abelian and has dimension $2d$, then there is no element of $H^2(G,\mathbb{R})$ whose $d$-th power is nonzero in $H^{2d}(G,\mathbb{R})$ (just look at the representation by bi-invariant forms), and there would have to be such an element if there were going to be even a symplectic structure on $G$, much less a Kähler structure.  Conversely, if $G$ is abelian, then, yes, since $G=\mathbb{R}^{2d}/\mathbb{Z}^{2d}$, and, for any left-invariant complex structure, $G$ is $\mathbb{C}^d/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda\subset\mathbb{C}^d$ is a lattice (i.e., a discrete subgroup of maximal rank $2d$).  Thus, there is a left-invariant Kähler structure, for example, (though there are others).

*Added on 21 Jan 2017:*  As for your second question, I believe I have a partial answer, which is 'If the center of $G$ is finite (i.e., $G$ is semisimple), then $G$ does not possess a balanced metric'.  Here is why:  It is my understanding that, if $G$ is a compact Lie group and $J$ is a left-invariant complex structure, then $J$ is one of the complex structures constructed by Samelson and Wang.  (See H.C. Wang, *Closed Manifolds with Homogeneous Complex Structure*, American Journal of Mathematics **76** (1954),1–32, which seems to indicate this though it doesn't state it explicitly.  Also, see the article mentioned by François in the comments below.)

In such cases, there exists a maximal toral subgroup $T\subset G$ that is $J$-complex, and the quotient $G/T$ inherits a complex structure such that the quotient map $\pi:G\to G/T$ is holomorphic.  Moreover, $G/T$ is not only Kähler, but an algebraic complex manifold to boot (in fact, it's the complete flag variety of $G$).

In particular, $G/T$ contains an algebraic (complex) hypersurface $Z\subset G/T$, whose preimage $X=\pi^{-1}(Z)\subset G$ is therefore a compact complex hypersurface in $G$.  Now if $\omega$ were a positive $(1,1)$-form on $G$ (with respect to the complex structure $J$) such that $\omega^{d-1}$ were closed (where $2d$ is the dimension of $G$), then the integral of $\omega^{d-1}$ over $X$ would be positive.  In particular, it would follow that the homology class of $X$ in $H_{2d-2}(G,\mathbb{R})$ were nonzero.

However, when $G$ is semi-simple (i.e., when its center is finite), we know by the Whitehead Lemma that $H_2(G,\mathbb{R}) = 0$, so Poincaré Duality implies that $H_{2d-2}(G,\mathbb{R})=0$ as well, contradicting the fact that the real homology class of $X$ must be nonzero.

I believe a more careful analysis of the cohomology ring of $G$ when the center of $G$ has positive dimension will lead to the result that $G$ can carry a balanced metric only when $G$ is abelian.

Comment: The answer to the first question goes back to [Samelson (1953)](http://purl.pt/2232) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=59287)), who after constructing invariant complex structures on even-dimensional compact Lie groups, observes (Remark 7c): "The complex manifolds described here are in general not Kähler manifolds (for semi-simple groups the second Betti number is 0)."

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert Bryant. This was very helpful. Regarding the second question, about balanced manifolds, should I post another question with it? It seems that it would help this site to be better organized.

Comment: @MaxReinholJahnke:  Well, you could wait to see if someone answers the balanced question, too.  I haven't had time to think about it yet, but someone may have.  While I'm writing, let me ask:  Is the balanced condition the same as requiring that the corresponding (1,1)-form is co-closed (rather than closed)?  I.e., if the manifold has dimension $2d$, we require that $\omega^{d-1}$ be closed.

Comment: Your guess that the Samelson-Wang complex structure is the only left-invariant one is right and proved in [Charbonnel-Khalgui (2004)](http://www.heldermann.de/JLT/JLT14/jlt1410.htm) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2040175)) — see their remark after the theorem on p. 167.

Answer (score 4):

To partial answer the first question:
Theorem (A.Borel- R.Remmert) Let $X$ be a connected, compact, homogeneous Kaehler manifold. Then $X$ is isomorphic to the product $Y \times A(X)$, where
$Y=G/P$ is a flag manifold and $A(X)$ is the Albanese manifold. More precisely, $Y$ is the base of the Tits fibration and the isomorphism is given by the product of the Tits fibration map and the Albanese map.

Comment: This immediately gives you Robert's answer, since $Y=G/P$ can't be a compact Lie group, as the maximal compact in $P$ sits inside a maximal compact in $G$, and is not trivial as it contains the maximal compact in a Cartan subgroup.

Comment: Of course that's true, but I think that the proof directly from cohomology (which only relies on the elementary Whitehead Lemma) is a bit more elementary than the Borel-Remmert Theorem.  Also, the OP didn't assume that the Kähler structure was left-invariant, just that the complex structure was (although left-invariance is a bit of a red herring anyway).

Comment: Thank you very much, Ben McKay. This was helpful, but I will accept Robert Bryant's answer because I think it is easier to understand.